# HashMap replaces entrys

Tags: java, android, replace, hashmap, android-volley

I don't know why, but my hashmap is replacing some of my entrys. Erase the old one and put the new. 
It's not even the oldest, and for some reason, it has only 4 slots, since the beggining.

Here is the code I'm using:

```
params = new HashMap<String, String>();
params.put("conta", usuario.getConta());
params.put("agencia", usuario.getAgencia());
params.put("data", consultaF);
params.put("dataI", "DataTeste");
```

When it gets on "agencia" key, the hashmap stores the entry, no problem. However when it gets on the "dataI" key, replaces the agencia entry for the "dataI" entry.

In another Activity class, this same class stores a total of 8 values. It's not a singleton. 
I've tried to change the keys but it doesn't work. I need to store this 4 values in the hashmap, cause I'm using the library volley to comunicate with a restfull webservice and these are the parameters for the ws.
 what can I do and why this replace is happening?

Comment: It is hard to answer without all code. In this example everything seems ok.

Answer (score 0):

Evidently `params` is overwritten. Check the code.

To ensure no new HashMap is assigned, in general one might start with a one-time initialisation.

```
final Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
```

Answer (score 0):

Resolved,
The Debuger doesn't show it properly, 
it wasn't replacing at all. The debugger show as it was replacing, but testing deeper, adding more parameters, the hashmap show more entries and the values were there.
The debugger is weird. 
when I ask the hashmap for the values it returned me right away all the values. 
Sorry I can't post pictures yet, or I would show you that was an debugger problem in eclipse adt.